Translational invariance $\neq $ Galilean invariance?
I have the impression that some literature say that Galilean invariance is broken by a uniform lattice. That is, although a uniform lattice like a tight binding model is translationally invariant, it is not Galilean invariant.
Could anyone expound this point?
As far as I can see, a discrete translation symmetry is quite similar to a continuum translation symmetry.
ps. Here we have a paper suggesting that a lattice system is not Galilean invariant.


Which literature? Which page?

By "Galilean invariance" do you mean continuous translational invariance and by "translational invariance" do you mean discrete translational invariance? Please define these two terms.

A lattice isn't translationally invariant because if you translate by a vector that does not point from the origin to a lattice site then you do not end up with the same lattice.  Therefore, it is not Galilean invariant.
